# C - Copying integer

Tags: c

so i am using `jansson` library and i want to set a value:
json_object_set_new(event, "error_code", json_integer(response->error_code));

The problem is that, i need to `free` `response` struct,  but still use the value i have set in `json_object_set_new`.

Should i copy the value from `response->error_code` and how can i do that?

Some context:

```
plugin_response: {
    if(!response->message && response->error_code == 0) {
            response->error_code = JANUS_AUDIOBRIDGE_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ERROR;
      if(response->error_cause == NULL) {
              response->error_cause = g_strdup_printf("%s", "Invalid response");
      }
    }

        json_t *event = json_object();
        if(!response->message && response->error_code != 0) {
            /* Prepare JSON error event */
            json_object_set_new(event, "audiobridge", json_string("event"));
            json_object_set_new(event, "error_code", json_integer(response->error_code));
            json_object_set_new(event, "error", json_string(response->error_cause));
        } else {
          event = json_deep_copy(response->message);
    }

        if(root != NULL)
            json_decref(root);
        if(jsep != NULL)
            json_decref(jsep);
        g_free(transaction);
        g_free(response);



return janus_plugin_result_new(JANUS_PLUGIN_OK, NULL, event);
}
```

**EDIT:** I am also using GLib, so if there is a nifty method for this, i am all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, i read this [This article](http://denniskubes.com/2012/08/20/is-c-pass-by-value-or-reference/) and i understood. I don't need to copy integer i am passing to `json_integer()`, because it's is not a pointer and is completely isolated from the structs integer.